# Орфография и орфоэпия

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

Всем привет. Я прошу помощи по орфографии и орфоэпии. У меня сильно хромает русский язык. Можете рекомендовать какие-то книги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С орфоэпией поможет орфоэпический словарь.
А с орфографией и пунктуацией – Д.Э. Розенталь, например. У него есть комплексные труды, включающие и орфографию, и пунктуацию, и лексику. Пишет, вроде, доходчиво.